# Simulating sent SMS on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, sms

Since debugging is extremely slow with Xcode 4.3 on iOS 5.1 when starting/installing the app on the device I use the simulator which starts much faster. (see my question regarding this issue here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541288/xcode-4-3-with-ios5-1-pauses-about-10secs-when-debug-starts-simulator-starts-i)

So all I need to do is something like this:

```
MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;
NSString *s = @"1234567";
picker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject: s];   
picker.body =smsTxt;
if (simulationMode) {
    MessageComposeResult result = MessageComposeResultSent;            <-----------
    [delegate messageComposeViewController:picker didFinishWithResult: result];
} else
    [delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Here the problem is now that when executing on iOS-Simulator the MFMessageComposeViewController can't be instantiated and always yields nil.

**Is there a way to create another object MyOwnMFMessageComposeViewController on iOS simulator which is compatible to MFMessageComposeViewController and can be passed in the same method like MFMessageComposeViewController?**

Something like this:

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;
    NSString *s = @"1234567";
    picker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject: s];   
    picker.body =smsTxt;
    if (simulationMode) {
        MyOwnMFMessageComposeViewController *mypicker = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mypicker.messageComposeDelegate = delegate;
        NSString *s = @"1234567";
        mypicker.recipients =[NSArray arrayWithObject: s];   
        mypicker.body =smsTxt;
        MessageComposeResult result = MessageComposeResultSent;   
        picker = (MFMessageComposeViewController) mypicker;          
        [delegate messageComposeViewController:picker didFinishWithResult: result];
    } else
        [delegate presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is called a 'mock object' and is often used in test driven development. Basically what you do is create a subclass of MFMessageComposeViewController. This subclass works exactly the same as mfmessagecomposeviewcontroller except you also create instance variables to show that something has happened.

So for example when your delegate calls messageComposeViewController:didFinishWithResult. The mock object would likely store the result and a flag that that method had been fired. Note that this won't actually send anything, but simply tells you that the delegate fired and on a real object will work.

Comment: How would I create a "mock Object" that yields something other than nil when created? I defined a subclass of MFMessageComposeViewController and wrote           MyMFMessageComposeViewController *myPicker = [[MyMFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init]; --> myPicker is still nil? Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... it may be that the subclass is still nil because its a subclass of something that doesn't work on simulator. Try just making it a subclass of nsobject that responds to your delegate protocol

Comment: yes - but this won't have the same structure as MFMessageComposeViewController and I can't coerce this to a MFMessageComposeViewController, so I can't call [delegate messageComposeViewController:picker didFinishWithResult: result];
-- and this is what I actually need to do

Comment: The best you are going to be able to do is create a mock object that has the same properties and responds to your delegate method. The simulator doesn't display mfmessagecomposeviewcontrollers so mock's are your best bet without testing on device